# Discover DatagramPacket Size

Tags: java, datagram

I am creating a program (P1) in java that will read a file and send it to another program (P2) through network.
I created a class called DataGrama that holds the file and some other informations that I need to send to P2.
I need to a byte array in P2 to receive data, but P2 don't know the size of the packet that is comming, is there a way to discover the packetSize so I can create the byte array with the size that I need?

Here is what I have in P1:

```
 DatagramSocket clientSocket = new DatagramSocket();
 InetAddress IPAddress = InetAddress.getByName(textField.getText());
 byte[] sendData = new byte[(int)myFile.length()];
 FileInputStream convertToBytes = new FileInputStream(myFile);
 convertToBytes.read(sendData);
 convertToBytes.close();
 DataGrama dataGrama = new DataGrama(0, 0, sendData);
 sendData = serializeClass(dataGrama);
 DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IPAddress, 9874);
 clientSocket.send(sendPacket);
```

In P2 I have something like this:

```
 byte[] receiveData = new byte[50]; //<-- Here is the problem, how do I discover the size of the incoming byte array?
 DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
 serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will just have to allocate it as the largest size you are expecting to receive.

HINT: if you allocate it as that size +1, then if you ever receive a `DatagramPacket` whose length is that size including the +1 you know you have received an oversize packet.

Comment: The problem is, the user can choose the file and I don't know the size of the file, so I don't have the maximum size.
In the end, it will be 3 Programs, the second receive from the first and fragment the packet in smaller ones to send to the third one, that will save the file again.

Comment: You can't hope to transmit entire files inside a single UDP datagram in the first place. The maximum practical size for a UDP datagram is 534 bytes according to some sources. You need to rethink your entire requirement if this is any guide.

Comment: Yeah, I asked my teacher and he said that if the file is too big, it should be fragmented to be sent.